# Spring Initializr to create WAR for tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-initializr

I would like to use the Spring Initializr to create WAR for tomcat...
Our DevOps are still not used to the idea of running java as a standalone and would like to have the application as a WAR in tomcat

I was able to produce a project but it seems like its producing a standalone spring boot application

I still want to use Spring Initializr to produce all the dependencies like :

- Rest Repositories
- JDBC template
- Quartz
- REST

One solution is to create a dynamic web project in eclipse and use Spring Initializr then just copy all the pom dependency into  the dynamic web project
is there a better way?

Comment: Select **More Options**, change JAR to WAR in the **packaging** section...

Comment: Also can create war with maven plugins

Comment: Thank you Deinum but how do i get the Eclipse project out of this?

Comment: Just import the project... It is no more complex than that. Eclipse will detect the fact it is a war project and make it a web project.

Comment: no its not doing it. it will not create it as dynamic web project and will not add it to tomcat, i have posted a new question on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616337/correct-way-of-creating-spring-initialize-project-and-using-it-as-a-dynamic-web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a **deployable war file** into an external container, you have to :

- Reconfigure your project to produce a **WAR**
- Declare the embedded container ( **Tomcat** ) dependency as **provided**

  ```
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
      ...
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      ...
  </dependencies>
  ```